# why doesn't port 80 show up via firewall-cmd command?

Tags: firewall, tcp-ip

Doesn't port 80/http need to be explicitly opened like other ports (such as 443/https or 8080/server), or is it a special case?

on my machine (CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611)

```
firewall-cmd --list-ports

8777/tcp 443/tcp 8080/tcp 8000/tcp
```

(nothing re: port 80)

Answer (score 0):

http is service and will show in services query.

Use `firewall-cmd –get-services` to show current active services.

A service in firewalld is described as an xml file. There is one section named ports. Ports section of service http is 80.

Comment: ok, and I suppose http in the services list can be associated with port 80 via /etc/services.  or is there a more direct association between service and port number?